# Installing MongoDB in Brew/rbenv for MEAN.io

Tags: ruby, mongodb, homebrew, mean-stack

I followed [this setup](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.9-mavericks) when installing Ruby to my Mac. From what I can understand, I installed Ruby via Homebrew, which seems to work great on my machine, and I don't need to prefix every command with `sudo`.

I'm now trying to install MongoDB, and have installed it with `brew install mongodb`. I think it's now installed because when I run `mongo --version` it returns this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
```

Now I'm trying to launch a mean app, but when I run `grunt` in the root directory, it stops at this and throws up this error:

```
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
**Could not connect to MongoDB. Please ensure mongod is running and restart MEAN app.**
```

I'm wondering if this has something to do with my $PATH, this is where it confuses me...?

When I run `which ruby` this path comes up:

```
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

When I run `which mongo`, this path comes up:

```
/usr/local/bin/mongo
```

Could this be the problem why it's saying could not connect to MongoDB, do I have it installed correctly?

I just want to be able to launch that MEAN app, but it seems something is wrong with the MongoDBV installation.

This is the error I get when I run `mongod`:

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
2014-10-07T16:14:48.885+0100 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=37641 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Rafs-Mac-Pro.local
2014-10-07T16:14:48.885+0100 [initandlisten]
2014-10-07T16:14:48.885+0100 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2014-10-07T16:14:48.885+0100 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2014-10-07T16:14:48.885+0100 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2014-10-07T16:14:48.885+0100 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimavericks.local 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-10-07T16:14:48.885+0100 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-10-07T16:14:48.885+0100 [initandlisten] options: {}
2014-10-07T16:14:48.887+0100 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2014-10-07T16:14:48.887+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2014-10-07T16:14:48.887+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-10-07T16:14:48.887+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-10-07T16:14:48.887+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-10-07T16:14:48.887+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-10-07T16:14:48.887+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-10-07T16:14:48.887+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-10-07T16:14:48.887+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-10-07T16:14:48.888+0100 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-10-07T16:14:48.888+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-10-07T16:14:48.888+0100 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2014-10-07T16:14:48.888+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere that you set mongo to automatically run.  To start it up this time, open a new terminal and run `mongod`

You can configure mongo to run on bootup by running this:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Note: you'll need to reboot for the above to take effect.

Right, to fix `Unable to create/open lock file:` error you'll need to do:

```
sudo chown -R <your-username> /data/db
```

Comment: Updated the question with the error I get when I run `mongod`.

Comment: I'm now getting `[initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017`. Is this good news?

Comment: Fantastic! I had to run `mongod` before I ran `grunt` in my mean directory, are you saying that configuring mongo to run on bootup will mean I don't have to run `mongod` every single time?